# Laravel same route, different controller

Tags: php, controller, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to have general home page
and a different homepage for logged-in users
I search a lot on google but I can't find what to put in my if statement

I tried something like this:

```
Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', function(){
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'homecontroller@index'));
    }
    else{
        Route::get('/', array('uses'=>'usercontroller@home'));
    }
}));
```

I also try with something like:

```
return Controller::call('homecontroller@index');
```

but it seems it's not for laravel 4

I tried a lot of other things so I think it's more a misconception problem

If you have any clue

thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most simple solution I can think of is:

```
<?php

$uses = 'HomeController@index';
if( ! Auth::check())
{
    $uses = 'HomeController@home';
}

Route::get('/', array(
     'as'=>'home'
    ,'uses'=> $uses
));
```

Or you can just route the url / to method index() and do the Auth::check() in there.

Comment: I was stucked in the route closure and you changed the perspective doing the test before... you are great! it perfectly works

Comment: This works but such programming logic litters your routes.php file and makes it harder to read. Using filters is a better option, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, but I can't find a solution for now using filters and stay at root "/"

Comment: @GladToHelp so how would you do this with filters?

Answer (score 9):

ok after discussions on this platform and other forums, I come back with a compact solution

```
Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', 'uses'=> (Auth::check()) ? "usercontroller@home" : "homecontroller@index" ));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// routes.php
Route::get('/', 'homecontroller@index');



// homecontroller.php
class homecontroller extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (!Auth:: check()) {
            return $this->indexForGuestUser();
        } else {
            return $this->indexForLoggedUser();
        }
    }

    private function indexForLoggedUser()
    {
        // do whatever you want
    }

    private function indexForGuestUser()
    {
        // do whatever you want
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks andreyco but this is not what I'm looking for. As you can see in my exemple I would like to route to an other controller so I prefer to do the test in the route file

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```
Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', function(){
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        Redirect::to('home/index'));
    }
    else{
        Redirect::to('user/index'));
    }
}));
```

So you are basically redirecting the user based on the Auth check instead of defining an additional route.

Or use route filters

```
Route::filter('authenticate', function()
{
    if (!Auth::check())
    {
        return Redirect::to('home/index');
    }
});

Route::get('home', array('before' => 'authenticate', function()
{
    Redirect::to('user/index');
}));
```

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters