# One url/route two different controller laravel 5 based on user logged in or not

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

How can I load different controllers based on user logged in or not?

What I'm trying to do is:

```
// in app/Http/routes.php

Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index',
]);


// modules/Lesson/Http/routes.ph

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/', [
        'uses' => 'Modules\Lesson\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index',
    ]);
});
```

So when user logged in, it shows `DashboardController@index`, otherwise `HomeController@index`

But it always loading `/login` form when user not signed in.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have seen following link [Laravel 5 Entrust one route - load different controller based on Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530821/laravel-5-entrust-one-route-load-different-controller-based-on-role). But I can't do like that since module is optional.

Comment: Did you try putting the auth route before the non-auth route?

Comment: Yes, i hv tried that. Takes the last route only