# Different controller depending on user role - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm not sure if this is good or bad practice, but I'm trying to load the same route with a different controller / method depending on the user role.

Tried to do some role filtering like below, but not sure if this is the way to go:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'role:admin'], function() {
   Route::get('/', 'FirstController@index');
});

Route::group(['before' => 'role:editor'], function() {
   Route::get('/', 'SecondController@index');
});


Route::filter('role', function($route, $request, $value) {
   // what to do here and is this the right way?
});
```

But I don't get it to work. How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Found this thread: [Laravel same route, different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892830/laravel-same-route-different-controller)

But the accepted answer:

```
if( ! Auth::check())
```

Always returns false in routes.php

Comment: `Middleware` makes it much simple. Try that way

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information on how I can call a different controller with middleware?

Comment: Am going to post a detail answer on that. might be that could help you

Comment: Fixed it by doing something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368433/single-laravel-route-for-multiple-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have something along these lines?

```
Route::group(['middlware' => ['web', 'auth']], function (Router $router)
{
    /** get the logged in user here **/
    Auth::loginUsingId(2);
    $user = Auth::user();

    //you can move this to some other function but just to get the idea out i did it this way.
    if ($user->hasRole('admin'))
    {
        $router->get('test', function ()
        {
            dd('admin');
        });
    }
    elseif ($user->hasRole('owner'))
    {
        $router->get('test', function ()
        {
            dd('owner');
        });
    }
});
```